# Kint exhausted memory limit

Tags: magento2

I want to use Kint to show my variables. So to install it I use composer by composer require raveren/kint

I put in my block "use \raveren\kint\Kint;" and in my template Kint::dump(1); to test but I get this error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 132928520 bytes) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/vendor/raveren/kint/decorators/rich.php
>   on line 66

Have you got an idea ? Or can you give me a better library to show PHP Objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) is generally pretty good, and widely supported. I've used it with good results and little overhead and not run into any issues.

xDebug overrides the standard var_dump.

Just a quick FYI, 805306368 bytes is a measly 768mb. A rather low memory limit for Magento, consider raising it.

Comment: Thanks but Xdebug is not convenient. The output isn't clear as Kint. I search a Kint alternative or a solution to fix my bug.